# Pushing a TableViewController from a view controller using story boards

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard, ios7

So I have a story board setup that uses a navigation controller and has two views- a view controller and a table view controller. I have a button in my view controller that links to the next view using the story board UI, but I have a second button that I want to only push the table view if a condition is met.

I'm struggling to figure out what code I have to write to mimic the functionality of control-click dragging from a button to a view.

Here's what I'm currently trying to do:

```
self.table = [[CSTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.table animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you could just connect the button on your first view controller to a push segue to the table view controller.

However, you said you wanted to only have the button invoke the table view controller (TVC) if some condition is met.

One way to handle that is to have the first view controller disable the button until the condition is met, and then enable the button. Then you could still connect the button directly to a segue.

Another way to handle it would be to create a segue from the first VC to the TVC and give it a unique identifier. (Make it a push segue.) Then in the IBAction method for the button on the first VC, check to see if the condition is met, and if it is, invoke the UIViewController method performSegueWithIdentifier:sender to invoke the segue.